# Changing a MapAdapters default element output name with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb

I created the following class to map a `Map<String, DynamicTarget>` to a `DynamicTarget[]`:

```java
class DynamicTargetMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<DynamicTarget[], Map<String, DynamicTarget>> {

    public DynamicTarget[] marshal(Map<String, DynamicTarget> arg0) throws Exception {
        DynamicTarget[] mapElements = new DynamicTarget[arg0.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (DynamicTarget d : arg0.values()) mapElements[i++] = d;
        return mapElements;
    }

    public Map<String, DynamicTarget> unmarshal(DynamicTarget[] arg0) throws Exception {
        Map<String, DynamicTarget> r = new HashMap<String, DynamicTarget>();
        for (DynamicTarget d : arg0) r.put(d.getName(), d);
        return r;
    }

}
```

The result is this:

```
<dynamicTargets>
    <item>
        ...
    </item>
    <item>
        ...
    </item>
    <item>
        ...
    </item>
</dynamicTargets>
```

But this is what I want to achieve:

```
<dynamicTargets>
    <target>
        ...
    </target>
    <target>
        ...
    </target>
    <target>
        ...
    </target>
</dynamicTargets>
```

What do i need to do to get the desired output?

Comment: Try annotating `DynamicTarget` with `@RootElement(name="target")`, and the `dynamicTargets` property with `@XmlElementRef`. Untested.