# How to name an object array element with jaxb? (default seems item)

Tags: java, jaxb

Same question has been asked 10 years ago: [Changing a MapAdapters default element output name with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402235/changing-a-mapadapters-default-element-output-name-with-jaxb)

I have a map for searching reasons but dont want its keys listed in the xml

```
 @XmlRootElement(name="attribute")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class ResponseObject {
        
        static class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Dokument[], HashMap<String, Dokument>> 
        {
            @Override
            public Dokument[] marshal(HashMap<String, Dokument> map) throws Exception {
                return map.values().toArray(new Dokument[0]);
            }
          
            @Override
            public HashMap<String, Dokument> unmarshal(Dokument[] list) throws Exception {
                HashMap<String, Dokument> map = new HashMap<String, Dokument>(); 
                for (Dokument dokument : list)
                    map.put(dokument.getId(), dokument);
                return map;
            }
        }
                
        private String mandant;
        @XmlElement(name="user")
        private String beauftragenderUser;
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
        private HashMap<String, Dokument> dokumente = new HashMap<String, Dokument>();
...
```

This is my dokument

```
 @XmlRootElement(name="dokument")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Dokument {
    
        private String id;
        private String timestamp;
        private String mimetype;
        private Long length;
        @XmlTransient
        private byte[] content;
...
```

In my response Dokument[] is rendered as follows

```
<attribute>
   <mandant>00001</mandant>
   <user>me</user>
   <dokumente>
      <item>
         <id>441255001001</id>
         <timestamp>2022-02-01-07.05.43.689000</timestamp>
         <mimetype>application/pdf</mimetype>
         <length>92913</length>
      </item>
   </dokumente>
</attribute>
```

All Dokument instances are rendered as item. But I never choosed item as instance element. item seems to be a default name for object array instances. I would like **item** to be named **dokument**.

```
<attribute>
   <mandant>00001</mandant>
   <user>me</user>
   <dokumente>
      <dokument>
         <id>441255001001</id>
         <timestamp>2022-02-01-07.05.43.689000</timestamp>
         <mimetype>application/pdf</mimetype>
         <length>92913</length>
      </dokument>
   </dokumente>
</attribute>
```

Does anybody know how to change this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.